# Javascript - Resize two divs vertically on window resize

Tags: javascript

There are two divs vertically having unequal height. The minimum height of each div can be `40px`.

When i resize the browser window, I want the divs to resize maintaining the aspect ratio.

[I have created a demo in JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/xeruxohaqi/edit?html,css,js,output). It works but it gets into `Maximum call stack`.

```
function divideEqually(h1, h2, diff) {
    let threshold = 40;
    let diffSplit = diff / 2;
    let leftOut1 = 0,
        leftOut2 = 0,
        leftOut = 0;

    if (h1 != threshold) {
        h1 = h1 + diffSplit;
    } else {
        leftOut1 = diffSplit;
    }
    if (h2 != threshold) {
        h2 = h2 + diffSplit;
    } else {
        leftOut2 = diffSplit;
    }

    diff = 0;
    if (h1 < threshold) {
        leftOut1 = threshold - h1;
        h1 = threshold;
    }
    if (h2 < threshold) {
        leftOut2 = threshold - h2;
        h2 = threshold;
    }

    diff = Math.ceil(leftOut1 + leftOut2);
    // error margin
    if (Math.abs(diff) > 0.5) {
        return divideEqually(h1, h2, diff);
    }
    return {
        h1: h1,
        h2: h2
    };
}

const qs = handle => document.querySelector(handle)
let initialHeight = window.innerHeight;

window.addEventListener('resize',()=>{
    const newHeight = window.innerHeight;
    const changeInHeight = newHeight - initialHeight;

    const h1 = qs("#top");
    const h2 = qs("#bottom")
    const h = divideEqually(h1.clientHeight,h2.clientHeight,changeInHeight);
    initialHeight = newHeight;

    h1.style.height = h.h1 + "px";
    h2.style.height = h.h2 + "px";

    // debug
    h1.innerHTML = h.h1;
    h2.innerHTML = h.h2;
})
```

Is their any better way of doing this or optimising the function ?

Comment: Do you know the height of the `div`s in advance? Your demo `div`s have equal height.

Comment: Yes I know the height of the div in advance. It can be anything (equal height, unequal height)

Comment: In the demo, the div's have unequal height

Answer (score 0):

No need for Javascript; modern browsers have got you covered. Just add the `flex` property to the `div`s' CSS. This example gives the `div`s a 65/35 split.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

#top {
  flex: 65 0 0%;
  min-height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
}

#bottom {
  flex: 35 0 0%;
  min-height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="top"></div>
  <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use flex. I would need the height in pixels and store it in localStorage.. So that in the next load, it remembers the last position.